# ORA-01732: data manipulation operation not legal on this view

Tags: oracle

I have this DML statement..

```
delete from  (select  key,value,computed, row_number()  OVER (Partition By key, value order by seq asc)  as a
from excelformats  a )
where A > 1
```

and this throws

```
ORA-01732: data manipulation operation not legal on this view
```

This statement basically selects duplicate rows from excelFormats table those to be deleted 
How can I revise so that

Comment: Change to iterate in records and delete one by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
DELETE FROM excelformats
 WHERE rowid not in 
            (SELECT MIN(rowid) 
               FROM excelformats
              GROUP BY key, value, computed);
```

This will delete duplicate rows in your `excelformats` table given the three key columns you stated.

Hope it helps...